# Handle categorical class labels for scikit-learn MLPClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have a handwritten dataset for classification purpose where the classes are from `a-z`. If I want to use [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), I think I cannot use such categorical classes directly because MLP implementation in scikit-learn only handles numerical classes. Thus, what is the appropriate action to do here? How about converting these classes to be numbered from 1-28, does it make sense? If not, does scikit-learn provide special encoding mechanism for class labels to handle this case (I guess one-hot encoding is not the option here)?

Thank you

Comment: Scikit learn can handle categorical class labels by itself. No need to do anything. Have you tried that ? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to preprocess the data, as scikit-learn only handles numeric values. In this case I wanted to predict the currency of a transaction. The currency is expressed in ISO code so LabelEncoder was used to transform it into numeric categories (ie: 1, 2, 3...):

```
#Import the object LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#defining class column
my_encoder = LabelEncoder()
my_class_currency = np.array(my_encoder.fit_transform(my_data['currency'])).reshape(-1,1)
#Create a "diccionary" to translate the categories into the actual values once you have the output
my_class_decoder = list(np.unique(my_data['currency']))
```